# JS: Separate Array items and display individual items in a table

Tags: javascript, arrays

In my application I get a JSON Object from a API and one of the items fetched from the api is the days of the week that the flight happens (in an array inside the main array).

[image: API JSON ARRAY SCREENSHOT]

In my HTML I've formatted a table to display the days of the week

[image: HTML LAYOUT SCREENSHOT]

The issue is that the amount of days depends, and each Flight has a different number of days. In my mind I need to:

1. Split the array of DAYS and get the amount of items
2. Display to inner html `<Td ID="SOME ID">` using for each so I only have the amount of rows needed.

The thing is: I have no clue on how to do it. And most of the websites are unclear.

Please HELP!

Currently this is my JS.

```js
document.getElementById('modalSchedule').innerHTML = flightData.weekdays; // Modal info Days Of Week

// FlightData is a variable of the entire JSON output
```

And this is my HTML:

```html
<div class="modalScheduleBody">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-sm">
        <thead>
            <th scope="col">
                <span class="badge badge-info">
                <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-calendar3-range" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M14 0H2a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v12a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h12a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V2a2 2 0 0 0-2-2zM1 3.857C1 3.384 1.448 3 2 3h12c.552 0 1 .384 1 .857v10.286c0 .473-.448.857-1 .857H2c-.552 0-1-.384-1-.857V3.857z"/>
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M7 10a1 1 0 0 0 0-2H1v2h6zm2-3a1 1 0 0 1 0-2h6v2H9z"/>
                </svg>
                SCHEDULE
                </span>
            </th>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <!-- DAY 1-->
            <tr>
                            <td scope="row">
                              <span>
                                <samp>
                                  MONDAY
                                </samp>
                              </span>
                            </td>
                          </tr>

                        <!--DAY 2 -->
                          <tr>
                            <td scope="row">
                              <span>
                                <samp>
                                  TUESDAY
                                </samp>
                              </span>
                            </td>
                          </tr>

                          <!-- DAY 3-->
                          <tr>
                            <td scope="row">
                              <span>
                                <samp>
                                  WEDNESDAY
                                </samp>
                              </span>
                            </td>
                          </tr>

                        <!-- DAY 4 -->
                          <tr>
                            <td scope="row">
                              <span>
                                <samp>
                                  THURSDAY
                                </samp>
                              </span>
                            </td>
                          </tr>

                        <!-- DAY 5 -->
                          <tr>
                            <td scope="row">
                              <span>
                                <samp>
                                  FRIDAY
                                </samp>
                              </span>
                            </td>
                          </tr>

                        <!-- DAY 6-->
                          <tr>
                            <td scope="row">
                              <span>
                                <samp>
                                  SATURDAY
                                </samp>
                              </span>
                            </td>
                          </tr>

                        <!-- DAY 7-->
                          <tr>
                            <td scope="row">
                              <span>
                                <samp>
                                  SUNDAY
                                </samp>
                              </span>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                          
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the array and just dynamically create each tr td samp and span and append them to the tbody of the table.

```
_table = document.querySelector(".modalScheduleBody table tbody");

flightData.weekdays.forEach(function(d){
   tr = document.createElement("tr");
   td = document.createElement("td");
   td.setAttribute("scope","row");
   span = document.createElement("span");
   samp = document.createElement("samp");
   samp.innerHTML = d;
   span.appendChild(samp)
   td.appendChild(span)
   tr.appendChild(td)
   _table.appendChild(tr)
});
```